# How to efficiently calculate prefix sum of frequencies of characters in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Say, I have a string

```
s = 'AAABBBCAB'
```

How can I efficiently calculate the prefix sum of frequencies of each character in the string, i.e.:

```
psum = [{'A': 1}, {'A': 2}, {'A': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, {'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 1}]
```

Comment: Finally you want one dict or you want a list of dicts for each char while reading?

Comment: @Vanjith I want a running counter of character frequencies.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do it in one line using  [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import accumulate

s = 'AAABBBCAB'
psum = list(accumulate(map(Counter, s)))
```

This gives you a list of `Counter` objects. Now, to get frequencies for any substring of `s` in O(1) time, you can simply subtract counters, e.g.:

```
>>> psum[6] - psum[1]  # get frequencies for s[2:7]
Counter({'B': 3, 'A': 1, 'C': 1})
```

Answer (score 19):

this is an option:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
s = 'AAABBBCAB'

psum = []
for char in s:
    c.update(char)
    psum.append(dict(c))

# [{'A': 1}, {'A': 2}, {'A': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 1}, {'A': 3, 'B': 2}, 
#  {'A': 3, 'B': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 1},
#  {'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 1}]
```

i use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in order to keep a 'running sum' and add (a copy of the result) to the list `psum`. this way i iterate once only over the string `s`.

if you prefer to have [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) objects in your result, you could change the last line to

```
psum.append(c.copy())
```

in order to get

```
[Counter({'A': 1}), Counter({'A': 2}), ...
 Counter({'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 1})]
```

the same result could also be achieved with this (using [`accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) was first proposed [in Eugene Yarmash's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55904471/4954037); i just avoid `map` in favour of a generator expression):

```
from itertools import accumulate
from collections import Counter

s = "AAABBBCAB"
psum = list(accumulate(Counter(char) for char in s))
```

---

just for completeness (as there is no 'pure `dict`' answer here yet). if you do not want to use `Counter` or `defaultdict` you could use this as well:

```
c = {}
s = 'AAABBBCAB'

psum = []
for char in s:
    c[char] = c.get(char, 0) + 1
    psum.append(c.copy())
```

although `defaultdict` is usually more performant than `dict.get(key, default)`.

Comment: We don't even need `Counter` here, a simple `defaultdict` will do @hiro-protagonist ,  check my answer below!

Comment: what makes you say `defaultdict` is 'simpler' than `Counter`? simpler in what way?

Comment: I didn't say simpler, I said `defaultdict` is a simpler data structure to represent the dictionary, then a  `Counter`, does that make sense?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh they are both subclasses of `dict`; the data structure of a counter is not more complicated that the one of a `dict`. or what am i missing?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, this considerations are misplaced. I've pointed time performance difference, but the OP should make his(her) own decision.

Comment: with a small risk of wrong usage, you could make this a generator and yield the original Counter at each step, pushing the possibly expensive copy to a `dict` to the consumer who might not need to

Comment: @WorldSEnder sure, that is a possibility. i created a list as the question suggested that shoud be the desired output...

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: Your answer came later than this one, it is the exact same structure with a slightly different type, it has the same complexity but with a more verbose output. You shouldn't advertise it here.

Comment: What answer are you talking about Eric, I don’t see one from you in the thread here! Also my comment was already pointed out to be a misplaced consideration!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh: I didn't write any answer because hiro's and Eugene's are good enough. If you agree that your comment was misplaced, you can always delete it.

Comment: Using the `dict` would be a more efficient approach than using either `defaultdict` or `Counter`, as the conversion at the end (to `dict`) is demanding.

Answer (score 7):

You actually don't even need a counter for this, just a defaultdict would suffice!

```
from collections import defaultdict

c = defaultdict(int)
s = 'AAABBBCAB'

psum = []

#iterate through the character
for char in s:
    #Update count for each character
    c[char] +=1
    #Add the updated dictionary to the output list
    psum.append(dict(c))

print(psum)
```

The output looks like

```
[{'A': 1}, {'A': 2}, {'A': 3}, {'A': 3, 'B': 1}, 
{'A': 3, 'B': 2}, {'A': 3, 'B': 3}, 
{'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}, 
{'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 1}]
```

Answer (score 6):

Simplest would be to use the Counter object from collections.

```
from collections import Counter

s = 'AAABBBCAB'

[ dict(Counter(s[:i]) for i in range(1,len(s))]
```

Yields:

```
[{'A': 1},  {'A': 2},  {'A': 3},  {'A': 3, 'B': 1},  {'A': 3, 'B': 2},
{'A': 3, 'B': 3},  {'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 1},  {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}]
```

Comment: Just to note, `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so there's little reason to replace the `Counter` with a plain `dict`.

Comment: I agree, but its more in line with what user specified as output.  I would keep the Counter objects myself as they have useful functions in addition to being a dict.

Comment: This is an elegant 1-liner so +1, but is quadratic rather than linear. I suspect that the similar solution by hiro protagonist is more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.8 you can use a list comprehension with an [assignment expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (aka "the walrus operator"):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> s = 'AAABBBCAB'
>>> c = Counter()
>>> [c := c + Counter(x) for x in s]
[Counter({'A': 1}), Counter({'A': 2}), Counter({'A': 3}), Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 1}), Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 2}), Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 3}), Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}), Counter({'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 1}), Counter({'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 1})]
```